# Can someone please give me an example of arrayfun in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, function

I am confused by the parameters and when trying to use it I keep getting told to use a function handle, (I do not even know what that is)?!

```
labelsAsChars = arrayfun(char,labels);
```

I want to convert an array of Ints into an array of Chars. `labelsAsChars` is what I want to store it in char is the function that turns an Int into a Char i.e. `char(97)` returns 'a'. labels is the 20 by 20 matrix of Ints.

Comment: Yes of course. [Here you go!](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)

Comment: labelsAsChars = arrayfun(char,labels); But when running it I get "Error using arrayfun
First input must be a function handle."

Comment: I'm wanting to convert an array of Ints into an array of Chars. labelsAsChars is what I want to store it in, char is the function that turns an Int into a Char i.e. char(97) returns 'a'. labels is the 20 by 20 matrix of Ints.

Comment: You don't need `arrayfun` to do that. Try the following in MATLAB: `a = [72  69  76  80  77  69]; b = char(a)`.

Comment: Thanks but what if I wanted to say add 25 to the Ints in a and then convert these numbers to char?

Comment: Then: `a = a + 25; b = char(a);` You can do simple operations like this on entire matrices in MATLAB.

Comment: Okay thank you I've got all that now!

Answer (score 2):

arrayfun is for using a function for each element of an array.  Basically if you have:

```
A = arrayfun(fun, S)
```

A is an array that you're assigning the value output, fun is the function that you are applying, and S is the array of things that you are applying the function to.  When it talks about the function handle it's referring to "fun" in the example, which needs to be a valid function.  In psuedocode that means something like this:

```
s = [1, 2, 3]
def add1(x)
return x+1;
end
a = arrayfun(add1, s);
puts a
```

the output would look like [2, 3, 4].

There's some additional reading about it here that I found helpful: http://function.name/in/Matlab/arrayfun